# How to inject a trait with macwire

Tags: scala, macwire

I have a Scala trait

```
trait UserRepository {
  def findByEmail(email: String): User
}
```

I would like to inject this into a service with MacWire

```
class AccountService(){
  val userRepo = wire[UserRepository]
}
```

And then use it in a test or class

```
class AccountServiceSpec {
  val userRepo = new UserRepositoryImpl()
  val accountSvc = new AccountService() //<--not manually injecting repo in service constructor
}
```

but I'm getting a compile error in the service class

> Cannot find a public constructor nor a companion object for
>   accounts.repository.UserRepository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to transform `userRepo` to class parameter, that allows macwire automatically provide its value for service:

```
import com.softwaremill.macwire._

case class User(email: String)

trait UserRepository {
  def findByEmail(email: String): User
}

class AccountService(val userRepo: UserRepository)

class UserRepositoryImpl extends UserRepository{
  def findByEmail(email: String): User = new User(email)
}

class AccountServiceSpec {
  val userRepo = new UserRepositoryImpl()
  val accountSvc = wire[AccountService] //<--not manually injecting repo in service constructor
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.